# SELECT AVERAGE ACROSS COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, select, average, coalesce, isnull

I hope one of you will be able to help me with my question.

I am building a simple course management program, which is able to store trainee data such as names, start_date, course_duration etc. One of the key fields is the choice of courses, their dates and assessment scores.

Now I would like to create a function which retrieves the average for all assessment courses that a user has taken.

I have structures my table in the following way:

user_id | name | start_date | team | course1 | course1_date | course1_assessment | course2 | course2_date | course2 assessment | course3 | course3_date | course3_assessment | etc...

Now I'm having a problem building the SELECT function that gives me the right Average for all assessments. It's all fine when all fields are populated but it might happen that the trainee hasn't taken some of the courses yet, but the average needs to be pulled out anywya (if i.e. course2_assessment field is NULL)

I'm trying to do sth. like:

"SELECT COALESCE(course1_assessment, course2_assessment, course3_assessment)/ (only a number of fields from the COALESCE(Array) with VALUES != NULL) FROM table WHERE name='$name'";

If someone can suggest a better way, like creating a larger number of tables please feel free to suggest.

Regards

Jacek

Comment: The better way is to normalize your schema to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to revamp your data model.  I can see at least three tables that could be broken out from the table you mention.

```
create table user(
   user_id int,
   name varchar
);

create table course(
    course_id int,
    name varchar
);

create table assessment(
    assessment_id int,
    user_id int,
    course_id int,
    name varchar,
    grade int
);
```

Then to get the average grade:

```
select avg(grade) as grade, user_id
from assessment
group by user_id;
```

This data model will prevent you from adding columns to the table every time a new course/assessment is created.  Instead, new assessments will result in a row in the assessment table.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to normalize your tables, as has been suggested.

As a second answer, this lets you keep your current schema.

There is not PIVOT in MYSQL like in SQL Server, but that would have been nice.

```
SELECT AVG(assessment)
FROM (
    SELECT name, course1_assesment assessment FROM `table` WHERE course1_assessment IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, course2_assesment FROM `table` WHERE course2_assessment IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, course3_assesment FROM `table` WHERE course3_assessment IS NOT NULL
) t
WHERE name = 'name'
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions. Now my question is, would i really need the course table? It seems to replicate the fields from the assessment table.

Comment: Was that the question to me? If so I wasn't criticising anybody, was just wondering if that's the best approach, since i want to avoid creating too many tables.

Comment: @Jack If a course never has more than one assessment then you can put the grades on the course table.  If courses have more than one assessment, assessment and course must be split.  You definitely should have course, user.

Comment: Thanks Kevin; there will be one assessment per course indeed so I suppose two tables will do in this case. I want to be able to do the following: 1. enter trainee details(name, start_date, departm.), 2. pull out trainee details (name, start_date, departm., courses attended + relevant assessment scores), 3. Pull out various matrix: i.e. average assessment score for all courses taken by a trainee, average assessment score for a given course taken by all trainees, 4. Show the number of fails (85% will be the pass mark) per course, 5. Create an alert system when a trainee is due to attend a course